# can the "Entry Manager" in EE 3.4.6 do more than "remove"

Tags: bulk

In EE 2 we were able to bulk-edit several articles at once -- mostly to change their status, the time/date of publication, and the wording of the headline. But in EE 3.5.6, there seems to be **less** capability. We can only **remove**. Is there any way around this, or do we have to buy an add-on? The "check -- with selected --" does not seem to make sense....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EE2 has edit option to change status and entry date of entries. unfortunately EE3 doesn't have anything like that till now. Let's hope they will add this in there future updates